# Check if a primary key value is referred in any other table

Tags: oracle, primary-key

I am using oracle database.

Is there a way I can check if the primary key value in one table is being used as a foreign key value (have any associations) in any other table?

Example: if I have the Student_id as primary key in STUDENT table. And there are other tables in the schema like CLASS, MARKS, SPORTS etc.

I have student_id=100 with me. I need to find out all the references of this student_id value '100' in the entire schema wherever it is linked as a foreign key from the parent table STUDENT.

Answer (score 3):

You can check dba_constraints:

Get the primary key constraint name:

```
select constraint_name 
from dba_constraints 
where owner = '<SCHEMA_NAME>' and table_name = 'STUDENT' and constraint_type = 'P';
```

Then check where that constraint is used:

```
select owner, table_name, constraint_name
from dba_constraints 
where r_constraint_name = '<result from previous query>' and constraint_type = 'R';
```

To get the column name of the referential constraint, you can use dba_cons_columns:

```
select owner, table_name, column_name 
from  dba_cons_columns
where constraint_name = '<constraint name from previous query>';
```

Plugging all of this together, you can do something like:

```
  SELECT fk.owner, fk.table_name, col.column_name
    FROM dba_constraints pk
    JOIN dba_constraints fk
      ON pk.constraint_name = fk.r_constraint_name
     AND fk.constraint_type = 'R'
    JOIN dba_cons_columns col
      ON fk.constraint_name = col.constraint_name
   WHERE pk.owner = :owner AND pk.table_name = 'STUDENT' AND pk.constraint_type = 'P';
```

Comment: Thanks Kris. But my problem is little extended. I need to find the references of the value of that constraint. Not the actual constraint name reference.
 
As I explained I need to find all the references of students with student_id 100 in the schema.

Comment: shouldn't it be..

JOIN user_cons_columns col
      ON fk.constraint_name = col.constraint_name

Answer (score 0):

I'm not as up on my Oracle as I should be, but I think this query should give you the Primary/Foreign Key relationship lookup you're after.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.all_constraints a
INNER JOIN sys.all_constraints b
    ON a.constraint_name = b.constraint_name
INNER JOIN sys.all_cons_columns c
    on c.constraint_name = b.constraint_name
WHERE a.constraint_type = 'P'
  AND b.constraint_type = 'R'
```

Comment: Thank you.I am confused, how to drill down based on the primay key columns value. Is there any easy way

Comment: I don't think simple is exactly the right word. I believe you'd need to get the objectid of whatever column it was in question. Then take that ID and search in the other tables where that field served as a FK and from there query for the specific value. You'd end up having several sub-queries in order to accomplish this. The query pertaining to the data would probably be your outter query, then the others would be interior queries. nested within one another I believe.

Answer (score -2):

```
select fk.table_name, col.column_name
from USER_constraints fk
JOIN user_cons_columns col
    ON fk.constraint_name = col.constraint_name
where constraint_type='R'
 and r_constraint_name in (
     select constraint_name 
     from user_constraints 
     where constraint_type in ('P','U') 
       and table_name='TABLE_NAME'
);
```